# Нужно, чтобы при нажатии self.printAction открывалось окно MyWindow (чтобы в открывшемся окне функционировал принтер, который уже написан)

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, pyqt6

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, \
    QMenu, QToolBar,QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtPrintSupport

from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Python Menus&amp;")
        self.resize(400, 200)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget(objectName='centralWidget')

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 90, 58); background-color: #105652; ")
        self.text = QTextEdit('Hello! Write here!')


        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)

        self._createActions()
        self._createMenuBar()

    def _createMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)
        editMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        editMenu.addAction(self.copyAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.pasteAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.cutAction)
        helpMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Help")
        helpMenu.addAction(self.helpContentAction)
        helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAction)
        printMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Print")
        printMenu.addAction(self.printAction)

    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("New")
        self.openAction = QAction("Open", self)
        self.saveAction = QAction("Save", self)
        self.exitAction = QAction("Exit", self)
        self.copyAction = QAction("&Copy", self)
        self.pasteAction = QAction("&Paste", self)
        self.cutAction = QAction("Cut", self)
        self.helpContentAction = QAction("Help", self)
        self.aboutAction = QAction("About", self)
        self.printAction = QAction("Print", self)
        #self.printAction.triggered.connect(self.show_window_1)

    def show_window_1(self):
        #app_1 = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.w1 = MyWindow()
        self.w1.show()
        #sys.exit(app_1.exec())

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.Window |
        QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("Печать изображений")
    def func(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Печать изображений")
        self.printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        self.printer.setPageOrientation(QtGui.QPageLayout.Landscape)
        self.file = None
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        btnOpen = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Открыть файл...")
        btnOpen.clicked.connect(self.openFile)
        vbox.addWidget(btnOpen)
        btnPageOptions = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Настройка &страницы...")
        btnPageOptions.clicked.connect(self.showPageOptions)
        vbox.addWidget(btnPageOptions)
        btnPreview = QtWidgets.QPushButton("П&росмотр...")
        btnPreview.clicked.connect(self.preview)
        vbox.addWidget(btnPreview)
        btnPrint = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Печать...")
        btnPrint.clicked.connect(self.print)
        vbox.addWidget(btnPrint)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.resize(200, 100)

    def showPageOptions(self):
        pd = QtPrintSupport.QPageSetupDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pd.exec()

    def preview(self):
        pp = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pp.paintRequested.connect(self._printText)
        pp.exec()

    def print(self):
        pd = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pd.setOptions(
            QtPrintSupport.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintToFile | QtPrintSupport.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintSelection)
        if pd.exec() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self._printImage(self.printer)

        self.show()

    def _printText(self, printer):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)
        color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(color))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(color))
        font = QtGui.QFont("Verdana", pointSize=42)
        painter.setFont(font)
        #pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.file)
        painter.drawText(printer.width(), printer.height(), QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip, self.text.text())
        painter.end()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, \\
    QMenu, QToolBar,QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtPrintSupport

from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Python Menus&amp;")
        self.resize(400, 200)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget(objectName='centralWidget')

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 90, 58); background-color: #105652; ")
        self.text = QTextEdit('Hello! Write here!')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)

        self._createActions()
        self._createMenuBar()

    def _createMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)
        editMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        editMenu.addAction(self.copyAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.pasteAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.cutAction)
        helpMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Help")
        helpMenu.addAction(self.helpContentAction)
        helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAction)
        printMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Print")
        printMenu.addAction(self.printAction)

    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("New")
        self.openAction = QAction("Open", self)
        self.saveAction = QAction("Save", self)
        self.exitAction = QAction("Exit", self)
        self.copyAction = QAction("&Copy", self)
        self.pasteAction = QAction("&Paste", self)
        self.cutAction = QAction("Cut", self)
        self.helpContentAction = QAction("Help", self)
        self.aboutAction = QAction("About", self)
        self.printAction = QAction("Print", self)
        self.printAction.triggered.connect(self.show_window_1)

    def show_window_1(self):
        self.w1 = MyWindow()
        self.w1.show()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.Window |
        QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("Печать изображений")

        self.text = QTextEdit('Type your text here')
        self.button = QPushButton('Print', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.func)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.text)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.resize(200, 100)

    def func(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Печать изображений")
        self.printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        self.printer.setPageOrientation(QtGui.QPageLayout.Landscape)
        self.file = None
        self.preview()

    def showPageOptions(self):
        pd = QtPrintSupport.QPageSetupDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pd.exec()

    def preview(self):
        pp = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pp.paintRequested.connect(self._printText)
        pp.exec()

    def print(self):
        pd = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pd.setOptions(
            QtPrintSupport.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintToFile | QtPrintSupport.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintSelection)
        if pd.exec() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self._printImage(self.printer)

        self.show()

    def _printText(self, printer):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)
        color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(color))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(color))
        font = QtGui.QFont("Verdana", pointSize=12)
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(printer.width(), printer.height(), QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip, self.text.toPlainText())
        painter.end()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Килобайт, мне нужно так же чтобы в открывшемся окне работали функции для принтера, но окно просто вылетает....

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вас, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent,                          # +
            flags=Qt.Window | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
            
        self.parent = parent                                            # +++
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Печать изображений")
        
        self.func()                                                     # +++
        
    def func(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Печать изображений")
        self.printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        self.printer.setPageOrientation(QtGui.QPageLayout.Landscape)
        
        self.file = None
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        btnOpen = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Открыть файл...")
        btnOpen.clicked.connect(self.openFile)                            # ???
        vbox.addWidget(btnOpen)
        
        btnPageOptions = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Настройка &страницы...")
        btnPageOptions.clicked.connect(self.showPageOptions)
        vbox.addWidget(btnPageOptions)
        btnPreview = QtWidgets.QPushButton("П&росмотр...")
        btnPreview.clicked.connect(self.preview)
        vbox.addWidget(btnPreview)
        btnPrint = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Печать...")
        btnPrint.clicked.connect(self._print)
        vbox.addWidget(btnPrint)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.resize(200, 100)
        
    def openFile(self):                                                  # ???
        pass

    def showPageOptions(self):
        pd = QtPrintSupport.QPageSetupDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pd.exec()

    def preview(self):
        pp = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pp.paintRequested.connect(self._printText)
        pp.exec()

    def _print(self):
        pd = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(self.printer, parent=self)
        pd.setOptions(
            QtPrintSupport.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintToFile | QtPrintSupport.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintSelection)
        if pd.exec() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self._printImage(self.printer)

        self.show()

    def _printText(self, printer):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)
        color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(color))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(color))
        font = QtGui.QFont("Verdana", pointSize=42)
        painter.setFont(font)
        #pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.file)
        
        painter.drawText(
#            printer.width(), 
#            printer.height(), 
#            QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip, 
#            self.text.text()
            42,                                                       # +++
            42,                                                       # +++
            self.parent.text.toPlainText()                            # +++
        )
        painter.end()
        

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Python Menus&amp;")
        self.resize(400, 200)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget(objectName='centralWidget')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 90, 58); background-color: #105652; ")
        self.text = QTextEdit('Hello! Write here!')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)

        self._createActions()
        self._createMenuBar()

    def _createMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)
        editMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        editMenu.addAction(self.copyAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.pasteAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.cutAction)
        helpMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Help")
        helpMenu.addAction(self.helpContentAction)
        helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAction)
        printMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Print")
        printMenu.addAction(self.printAction)

    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("New")
        self.openAction = QAction("Open", self)
        self.saveAction = QAction("Save", self)
        self.exitAction = QAction("Exit", self)
        self.copyAction = QAction("&Copy", self)
        self.pasteAction = QAction("&Paste", self)
        self.cutAction = QAction("Cut", self)
        self.helpContentAction = QAction("Help", self)
        self.aboutAction = QAction("About", self)
        self.printAction = QAction("Print", self)
        
        self.printAction.triggered.connect(self.show_window_1)

    def show_window_1(self):
        self.w1 = MyWindow(self)                                  # +++  (self)
        self.w1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]